# for biz_wacore_1 Cannot start service wacore: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting

Tags: docker, docker-compose, whatsapp

I am trying to pull image of whatsapp core and run them in docker in my linux machine, I am providing code of docker-compose.yml

**

> for biz_wacore_1  Cannot start service wacore: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh\": stat /opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh: no such file or directory

** is error I am having

Tried using docker-compose up with sudo command
code in my docker-compose.yml

services:

```
wacore:
image: docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v2.19.4
command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
volumes:
 - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
env_file:
  - db.env
environment:
  # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
  WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
  ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
depends_on:
  - "db"
network_mode: bridge
links:
  - db


waweb:
image: docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v2.19.4
command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
ports:
 - "9090:443"
volumes:
 - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
env_file:
  - db.env
environment:
  WACORE_HOSTNAME: wacore
  # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
  WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
  ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
depends_on:
  - "db"
  - "wacore"
links:
  - db
  - wacore
network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: you should try using a newer version of the client. The latest versions can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/changelog